# Create brand new XML node to append as child to other node

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I would like to create a new XML node to append to an existing one in my XML file. 
Specifically, the structure of the file is:

```
<contract>
    <trade></trade>
    <trade></trade>
</contract>
```

My idea is to get each `<trade>` node and append a *new* child to it. 
This child should look like this:

```
<tradeSource></tradeSource>
```

My question is, how do I define this new child to append? It doesn't seem I can find the right object to create on VBA (although the library MSXML v3.0 has been referenced in the project) and I don't manage to find such a sample of brand-new node anywhere on the web. My pseudo-code:

```
XMLFile.Load(myFileFullName)
Set tradeNodes = XMLFile.getElementsByTagName("trade")
For Each trade In tradeNodes 
    Set newNode = ???? '<-- how to fill this?
    trade.appendChild(newNode)
Next trade
```

Comment: If you need to append more than one child, many siblings/parants, grouping by nodes, with complex related logic, consider XSLT, the transformation xml language. And yes, Excel VBA can run XSLT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
Set newNode= XMLFile.CreateElement("price");
newNode.InnerText = "19.95"
trade.appendChild(newNode)
```

Please note that both variables `trade` and `newNode` should be declared as `IXMLDOMNode` (type defined in the library `msxml6.dll`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It actually creates the node, but the method "appendChild" fails when I try to append it. It seems to work only into the XMLFile object. Any idea?

Comment: Finally, it was just a matter of using the correct object type. I've modified your answer, hence I've accepted it. Thanks a lot!