# Add tags after specific tag in XML file using VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I am not an expert in macros and seeking help to add new tags after and before specific tags in a xml file.

I need as in second image,i need to insert a new tag `<CONTENT TYPE="text/html"><![CDATA[` after `<CHOICE ID="0">`. Also i need to insert a new tag `]]></CONTENT>`before `</CHOICE>`.

[image]

[image]

I appreciate your kind help.

Comment: We expect to see your attempts at coding this in line with the guidance given in [ask] and [mcve], otherwise this should be closed as too broad. Some research is expected of those asking questions.

Comment: Please read [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and include your code as text formatted as code block whithin your question ([edit]).

Answer (score 0):

The most neat option would be to load your xml into an XML Document Variable. You need to add a reference in VBA for that. It's pretty well explained here:

https://bettersolutions.com/vba/xml/microsoft-xml.htm

You can select nodes using [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_nodes.asp) and then remove for instance the `InnerText` of the selected node.

You can also insert new Nodes into your XML file. [This answer might help you with that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38104650/3927703)

Comment: Thanks Alex. I found a way to replace tags.